# Composite key for multiple tables: do I need a separate query to check table type?

Tags: mysql

I have a db model similar to this: [Foreign key for multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895128/foreign-key-for-multiple-tables).

I have `account` table. An `account` may be of type `venue` or `band`. I decided to make a composite key in account table: `id_account | type` - together they'd make up a PK (type may be venue or band or their numeric equivalents)

I know how I'd e.g. select all venues with data from `account` table as well: `SELECT account.*, venue.* FROM venue INNER JOIN account ON (venue.id=account.id AND type=venue)`.

Now, I have an administration panel in which user has his account (which is one of those type - venue or band). When he logs, the panel is different for venue accounts and for bands accounts. **Do I need one query to check the type of account (let's say it's venue) and then another query to the `venue` table to grab his data?** Otherwise - can I do something similar to:

```
SELECT ... FROM IF(type=venue, venue, band)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to this. It's probably not too expensive to do the two queries but if you want you could join the 'account' query to both 'band' and 'venue' tables (by some unique ID for either) then take the appropriate column from the result depending on the 'account type' column in the result.

Comment: Yep, so easy, I have no idea why I didn't think about it. Thanks!:)